# Mac OS X Finder file selection events?

Tags: macos, events, mac, finder

Does OS X fire events when I select files using its Finder app?

Comment: rather well disguised programming question.....

Comment: ?? this is not a programming question. i simply want to know if the OS fires such events at all. file selections are not file system events, so the events must come directly from Finder. i'm wondering if Finder supports that.

Comment: @Paul thanks for clearing that up.  Migrating to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

No.

However,  you can add an entry to the context menu appearing for files selected in the Finder. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1). You can just use Automator, too.